# missing argument on laravel update

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working with laravel 4. I have created an edit form like below:

```
 {{ Form::model($v, array('route' => array('insur_docs.update', $v->id),'method' => 'PUT','class'=>'form-horizontal')) }}
```

and update route

```
Route::put('insur_docs/update', array('as' => 'insur_docs.update', 'uses' => 'Insur_DocController@update'));
```

The problem it shows is:

> Missing argument 1 for Insur_DocController::update()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your route, you need to add `/{id}` to it. Here's a test I did:

```php
class Insur extends Eloquent {

}

Route::put('insur_docs/update/{id}', array('as' => 'insur_docs.update', 'uses' => 'Insur_DocController@update'));

Route::get('test', function() {

    $v = new Insur;

    $v->id = 1;

    return Form::model($v, array('route' => array('insur_docs.update', $v->id),'method' => 'PUT','class'=>'form-horizontal'));

});
```

And the generated form open was:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/insur_docs/update/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="V0TP6LbCjO1kGF6LCLObEi6hofbW5ZgNo5Kz7nQ3">
```

Comment: Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'national.insur__docs' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `insur__docs` where `id` = 1 limit 1) I haven't used insur__docs anywhere. why this error?

Answer (score 1):

```php
Route::put('insur_docs/update/{id}', array('as' => 'insur_docs.update', 'uses' => 'Insur_DocController@update'));
```